# Expo live reloading not working after an upgrade

Tags: react-native, expo

Unable to use live reload anymore, after upgrading expo cli, tried downgrading still doesn't work

using a real android native app to load the app, and logged in

Comment: Did you validate that the option was checked in context menu in expo client dev mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After metro bundler worked, turned production mode off, and it works